# What Use Cases are Appropriate for JScript.NET?

Tags: use-case

In this Stack Overflow question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471332

I learned that [Jscript is not dead after all](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkx7dfw1.aspx). Yay!

But what is JScript.NET good for?

According to [this article](http://odetocode.com/code/80.aspx), you can use it to provide C# with an Eval function.  That's neat, but it seems like kind of an edge case.

If you were after first-class scripting capability, doesn't PowerShell fit the bill?

Comment: Man, this makes me really wish I had Visual Studio 2010 at work. I'm stuck with 2008 so I can't try out some JScript :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [JSCript's Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript#JScript_.NET):

> JScript .NET can be used for ASP.NET pages and for complete .NET applications, but the lack of support for this language in Microsoft Visual Studio place it more as an upgrade path for classic ASP using classic JScript than as a new first-class language.

JScript.NET would allow one to write a server side website in something that resembles Javascript. It can allow what the *nix community has with Node.js (server side javascript) on Windows servers (yes I know that there is a Windows port of Node).

> If you were after first-class scripting capability, doesn't PowerShell fit the bill?

The thing is, JScript.Net creates an executable file. So you could write a full-fledged program in it and deploy it rather than just a script with PowerShell. Granted, I don't know of anybody who would want to do that, but apparently Microsoft believes there is at least a handful that do.

Comment: Wikipedia's article appears to be a bit [out of date.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bf5fs13.aspx)

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes, it most certainly does. None the less, you are still able to create executables using JScript, as pointed to in the MSDN documentation you linked to